# Can you get a second romance chance on companions

Tags: fallout-4

Recently I failed the final check to romance piper but have passed previous checks and would like to have her as my romance option.

Is it possible to get a second chance to romance a companion and if so is it dependent on passing earlier romance checks?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible, I've experienced it myself with Cait. I failed it the first time, said we were best friends the second and then tried, and passed, romancing the third time.

The first try was after finishing her side quest. The second was me talking to her and going through the dialogue options. The third was her initiating a conversation with me after fast-traveling.

Comment: This game is so unrealistic, everyone knows you can't get out of the friendzone

Comment: It happens to my female Vault Dweller too, with Preston. I intentionally avoided the romance path, and now he occasionally makes me choose between thanking him or going out with him. It's like the game doesn't care that I don't want a relationship...

Comment: @Nolonar I was having so much trouble shutting down Preston I just dismissed him and sent him to a settlement I don't go to. Restraining order.

Comment: @Nolonar PC gender doesn't matter either. Apparently, in Fallout 4, everyone is pansexual and comfortable with polyamory.